# Making 3 screens work

Tags: video, display

I have `Lenovo Thinkpad T400`.

It is currently on docking station and I have 1 dell screen.

I have 2 extra identical screens that I am trying to arrange on left and right side of my existing main screen.

But I guess my video card - `VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series` - only has 1 connection.

What are my (economical) options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most laptop video cards can only handle two monitors at a time T - even if they have more than one port. If you want any more you really need to run one of the external monitors off something else.

If you're using the 'mini' dock, you'd need to look at running one monitor off a USB-> video out adaptor - quite a few of them are [displaylink](http://www.displaylink.com/) based, though matrox also makes them.

If you're using the advanced dock, [apparently it you can use a video card with it](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T400-Advanced-Docking-Station-and-Dual-Monitors/td-p/342579) and you may be able to slot in a video card in there instead

Comment: I think, usb->dvi out adapter is the cheapest option for me. I will see if video quality is not that bad, I will go with it.